# joi validation: Set minimum array length conditionally

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I have an array field which i would like to ensure that it has at least one element when a condition is met:

```
genre:Joi.array().includes(data.genres).when('field'{is:'fieldValue',then:Joi.required()})
```

If i changed the 'then' field with Joi.required().min(1), it complains.

Can i do this with Joi?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You didn't mention what the error message was, but testing your code I suppose you got:

> TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'min'

This error occurs because [`min()`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi#arrayminlimit) is a function of the array type. In the `then:` part you create a new validation object and Joi doesn't know you expect an array there. So you need to specify it:

```
then: Joi.array().min(1).required()
```

The full validation code is:

```
genre: Joi.array().includes(data.genres).when('field', {is: 'fieldValue', then: Joi.array().min(1).required()})
```